# MySQL One row for each hour 00:01:00 and 23:59:00 interval of the day

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I'm trying to get one row for each hour of the day, which I intent to left join certain data to.

I need selected the **00:01:00** and **23:59:00** interval hour for each day.

I have tried this solution but I can't selected **00:01:00** and **23:59:00** interval hour but only **00:00:00** and **23:00:00** interval hour.

How to do resolve this ?

Can you help me please ?

Thank you in advance or any help.

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT(CURDATE(),' ','00:00') + INTERVAL (d0*10+d1) hour  AS mydate
FROM (
SELECT 0 AS d0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2
) AS t1
cross JOIN (
SELECT 0 AS d1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION 
SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) AS t2
WHERE (d0*10+d1) < 24
order by d0,d1;
+---------------------+
| mydate              |
+---------------------+
| 2020-03-10 00:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 01:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 02:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 03:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 04:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 05:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 06:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 07:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 08:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 09:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 10:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 11:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 12:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 13:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 14:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 15:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 16:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 17:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 18:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 19:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 20:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 21:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 22:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 23:00:00 |
+---------------------+
24 rows in set
```

*Edit 01*

I need this result :

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
| start_date          | end_date            |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2020-03-10 00:01:00 | 2020-03-10 01:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 01:01:00 | 2020-03-10 02:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 02:01:00 | 2020-03-10 03:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 03:01:00 | 2020-03-10 04:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 04:01:00 | 2020-03-10 05:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 05:01:00 | 2020-03-10 06:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 06:01:00 | 2020-03-10 07:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 07:01:00 | 2020-03-10 08:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 08:01:00 | 2020-03-10 09:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 09:01:00 | 2020-03-10 10:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 10:01:00 | 2020-03-10 11:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 11:01:00 | 2020-03-10 12:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 12:01:00 | 2020-03-10 13:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 13:01:00 | 2020-03-10 14:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 14:01:00 | 2020-03-10 15:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 15:01:00 | 2020-03-10 16:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 16:01:00 | 2020-03-10 17:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 17:01:00 | 2020-03-10 18:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 18:01:00 | 2020-03-10 19:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 19:01:00 | 2020-03-10 20:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 20:01:00 | 2020-03-10 21:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 21:01:00 | 2020-03-10 22:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 22:01:00 | 2020-03-10 23:00:00 |
| 2020-03-10 23:01:00 | 2020-03-10 23:59:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect.

Comment: What have you actually **tried**? Where is that "23:59:00 interval hour"?

Comment: @GMB Please see *Edit 01* in my first question

Comment: @NicoHaase Please see *Edit 01* in my first question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to generate a hours table. If so, I would recommend outputing two columns: one for the lower bound of the interval (which will be inclusive), the other for the upper bound (which should be exclusive)

```
SELECT 
    CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL (d0 * 10 + d1) hour  AS start_date,
    CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL (d0 * 10+d1 + 1) hour  AS end_date
FROM (SELECT 0 AS d0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) AS t1
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 AS d1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION 
    SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 
) AS t2
WHERE (d0 * 10 + d1) < 24
ORDER BY d0,d1;
```

This [produces a resultset like](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2339e1b9070fc804f4684ea562beecc2):

```
start_date          | end_date           
:------------------ | :------------------
2020-03-10 00:00:00 | 2020-03-10 01:00:00
2020-03-10 01:00:00 | 2020-03-10 02:00:00
2020-03-10 02:00:00 | 2020-03-10 03:00:00
...
2020-03-10 21:00:00 | 2020-03-10 22:00:00
2020-03-10 22:00:00 | 2020-03-10 23:00:00
2020-03-10 23:00:00 | 2020-03-11 00:00:00
```

You can then join that with your original table with half-open interval, like so:

```
SELECT ...
FROM myintervals i
LEFT JOIN mytable t 
    ON t.date >= i.start_date and t.date < i.end_date
```

The upside of this approach is that it properly handles the first and last minute of each interval.

---

**Edit**: to generate your exact desired results, you can do:

```
SELECT 
    CURRENT_DATE 
        + INTERVAL (d0 * 10 + d1) hour 
        + INTERVAL 1 minute AS start_date,
    CURRENT_DATE 
        + INTERVAL (d0 * 10+d1 + 1) hour 
        - INTERVAL (case when d0 * 10+d1 = 23 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) minute AS end_date
FROM (SELECT 0 AS d0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) AS t1
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 AS d1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION 
    SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 
) AS t2
WHERE (d0 * 10 + d1) < 24
ORDER BY d0,d1;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=114d894ad5b3ffaf316e0668e54c3bb6)**

Comment: thank you, please see **Edit 01** in my first question

Comment: @Golia: yes I have seen your edit. I still tend to think that what I am suggesting would better fit your need (if not, please explain).

Comment: Really appreciated your help but instead 00:00:00 value I need 00:01:00 value on start_date...

Comment: @Golia: why do you want that?

Comment: Because I need row of 59 minutes interval for each day